Repairing gypsum sub floor. Some questions
I'm redoing my bathroom. I have everything ripped out and need to patch the gypsum around the shower and toilet supply.
I bought some USG advanced skim coat ahead of time because I knew it was needed. Now I'm trying to prep everything correctly. USG states to use Fusion primer if its dusty and chalky, Now mine isnt really that. The water did turn some of it to dust but that is now all cleaned up. Now its just porous holes.
Do I need a primer before the skim coat? I found a single website with Fusion primer but its quite expensive for just my small need ($120). Will another brand or type work?
After patching I plan on applying mapei prim grip on top to prep for schluter ditra

Gypsum is not used for a subfloor. Are you working on a floor or a wall?

@RMDman Gypsum underlayment does exist, generally as a layer above structural concrete for purposes of leveling, detailing, and smoothness. The question might benefit from specifying the age and condition of the current base material, and possibly pictures of the specific areas in question-- but it does seem valid in general terms.

@Jay, interesting,  i have never encountered it.  is it water-soluble like drywall?

Not an expert, but my understanding is gypsum is just the fine aggregate in a cementitious product. So once it cures the subfloor is porous and semi-permeable, but not soluble. In North America it's much more common in commercial structures than single family homes, so probably a smaller pool of people to answer on this stack.

You are correct and yes it's making difficult to find best practices. It's a condo. After a sleep it occured to me that if the mapei prim grip primer can bond between gypcrete and thinset then why not bind between two layers of gypcrete. So I think I will do that and call it good

I suspect you are correct, but it's too far outside my area to attempt an answer. For future reference, you're more likely to get quality answers quickly if you include those details in the question: redoing a bathroom floor of gypsum leveling compound on concrete beams, the damaged areas are [details, maybe picture], my concern is [X]. There's great knowledge in SE and much less silliness compared to forums, but it does take some practice to best call it forth. Welcome to the site!

Gotcha. Thanks! @JayMcEh
